# What is the "best" way to get 3 different SUM using a single query in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This appears to be subjective but is not.

Given:

```
Table with the ff. field:

 - userid
 - breakstart
 - breakend
 - minutes
 - breaktype
```

Goal:
Get the `SUM()` of each type of break of a particular `user` inclusive of `breakstart` and `breakend`

What I've done so far:
The simplest that I can think of is to do 3 separate queries, like so...

```
SELECT SUM(minutes) as totalbreak 
FROM `breaklog`
WHERE
    userid = <some userid>
      AND
    DATE(breakstart) = "2015-06-11"
      AND
    DATE(breakend) = "2015-06-11"
        AND
    breaktype = "1"
# just feed breaktype with valid types i.e. ("1", "2", "3")
```

Am just trying to know if there is a better way to achieve my goal, probably with just one single query? Or is that even possible? Or is it better to get ALL `breaktypes` and do the filtering outside of the SQL engine, btw am using PHP in the backend.

Thanks in advance for all the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT breaktype, SUM(minutes) as totalbreak 
FROM `breaklog`
WHERE
    userid = <some userid>
      AND
    DATE(breakstart) = "2015-06-11"
      AND
    DATE(breakend) = "2015-06-11"
        AND
    breaktype IN ("1", "2", "3")
group by breaktype
```

Answer (score 2):

You  can  try this one also with  **Group by Having**

```
SELECT breaktype, SUM(minutes) as totalbreak 
FROM breaklog
WHERE
    userid = <some userid>
      AND
    DATE(breakstart) = "2015-06-11"
      AND
    DATE(breakend) = "2015-06-11"
group by breaktype
Having breaktype IN (1, 2,3)
```

Comment: seems the same in speed when I tried to benchmark your answer with jarlh